# Summing positive and negative elements from two NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, lambda

```
>>> x1
array([[ 0.,  -1.,   2.],
       [ 3.,  -4.,  2.],
       [ -2.,  1.,  -8.]])

>>> x3
array([[ 0.,  -5.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  0.,  -3.],
       [ 3.,  2.,  8.]])
```

I need two matricies to be output: `S` and `T`, such that `X` is the sum of all positive values in `X` and `Y`, and `T` is the sum of all negative values in `X` and `Y`.

For example:

```
      S = array([   [ 0.,  0.,  4.],
                    [ 6.,  0.,  2.],
                    [ 3.,  3.,  8.]])

      T = array([   [ 0.,  -6.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  -4.,  -3.],
                    [ -2.,  0.,  -8.]])
```

I am using Python 2.6.7.

Comment: So you've tried anything? Atleast Googling the problem statement?

Comment: I tried to use nditer. but stuck operating on two indexes for two matrix while collecting them in two arrays

Comment: If you have tried something then please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30400853/edit) your question and add the details

Comment: @YXD , you are correct, I made a mistake in preparing the output -- I have fixed it

Comment: What happens if there is a positive and a negative number when you perform your calcuation? For example, what would be the output in `posArray` and `negArray` if S[0][2] were `-2`?

Comment: @Bhargave Rao, I don't have leads to processed I looked at [link](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2000/09/27/numerically.html?page=3)

Comment: @jwir3, all Iam trying to do is add +ve and -ves together, in separate matrix and fill it with 0 on the other side, I am going to review following answers .. most likely they will work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.clip()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) to selectively add

```
In [140]: x1.clip(min=0) + x3.clip(min=0)
Out[140]:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  8.]])

In [141]: x1.clip(max=0) + x3.clip(max=0)
Out[141]:
array([[ 0., -6.,  0.],
       [ 0., -4., -3.],
       [-2.,  0., -8.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as `clip` you can do this by multiplying by boolean arrays:

```
>>> x1 * (x1 > 0) + x3 * (x3 > 0)
array([[ 0., -0.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  8.]])
>>> x1 * (x1 <= 0) + x3 * (x3 <= 0)
array([[ 0., -6.,  0.],
       [ 0., -4., -3.],
       [-2.,  0., -8.]])
>>>
```

Comment: which way will be better? I like you way since by looking at it makes sense but I have decent size (2k x 1k) matrix and I do this 100K times

Comment: Probably `clip` is better. But maybe you could post a question about your broader problem. Sometimes you can avoid the issue [altogether](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: Thank you, there is no broader problem.. this  is the problem. we are using 3rd party lib that requires matrix in this format, we have about 100k matrix that we need to pass split way and 3rd party will do the magic -- black box--   Thank you for your answer and explanation.

Comment: @XYD, since I move forward, I realized that the matrix size I have is not same for all matrix, meaning I have one matrix (S) of shape(8,5) and another of (T)  shape(2,9) ..  i need to have new matrix shape (8,9) -- I tried `zeros()` but didn't get the results I needed. any suggestion ?

Comment: @Sendi_t best thing is to post a new question on this and show an example of expected inputs and output

Comment: YXD, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463245/extend-different-shapes-dimension-matrices-in-python) is the new q. pls. see if you can assist