# Extend different shapes/dimension matrices in python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make two matrices same dimension/shape padding with zeros..

for e.g. I have

```
>>> x
array([[ 1.,  -1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1., - 1.]])
>>> 
>>> 
>>> y
array([[ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ -2.,  2.]])
```

Output I want

```
x1 = array([[ 1.,  -1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  -1.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])

y1 =array([[ 2.,  2., 0.],
           [ 2.,  2., 0.],
           [ -2.,  2., 0.]])
```

any help? I looked up the "pad" but the numpy version we are using is older so it does not have pad. ( numpy ver. 1.6.x)

I also looked up some solutions but they are specific to shape, in my case the shape is dynamic -- and the operation needs to be fast -- as I do this over a large matrices and many times

Comment: How come you can't upgrade your numpy version?

Comment: I would like to ... but it affects many other projects -- otherwise I have to get special exception to go solo for my project.. and q. will be raised why cant we do it in this version?

Comment: This is a common problem - you should read up on Conda environments and/or virtualenv which are designed for exactly this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every array has a `shape`:

```
>>> x = np.array([[ 1.,  -1.,  1.],
...               [ 1.,  1., - 1.]])
>>> y = np.array([[ 2.,  2.],
...               [ 2.,  2.],
...               [ -2.,  2.]])
>>> x.shape
(2, 3)
>>> y.shape
(3, 2)
```

We just need to compute the "maximum shape" and use that for the new arrays:

```
>>> shape = np.maximum(x.shape, y.shape)
>>> x1 = np.zeros(shape)
```

We can then copy the data from the original arrays into the corresponding parts of the new arrays:

```
>>> x1[:x.shape[0], :x.shape[1]] = x
>>> y1 = np.zeros(shape)
>>> y1[:y.shape[0], :y.shape[1]] = y
```

Results

```
>>> x1
array([[ 1., -1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> y1
array([[ 2.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  0.],
       [-2.,  2.,  0.]])
>>>
```

Comment: golden! , just quick q. here we are creating an empty array of zeros for x1, y1 of maximum shape, and than updating it --- I have matrix of 2k x 1k ( approximately ) since rows and column varies a little bit.. That means I will be holding 4 matrix at a time in memory.. do you think it will light enough? or should I loop?

Comment: I doubt you will run out of memory as each of those arrays will be ~16MB. Also the code `y1[:y.shape[0], :y.shape[1]] = y` will also just copy data into the previously allocated/zeroed memory rather than reallocating memory.

Comment: Thanks! ~16MB ? as they are all (same) zeros (floats), wouldn't it optimize memory space? and only updated matrix will be actual size? is there any other lib that can do that?

Comment: This is basically what `pad` does, but with more options - create the destination array of the correct size, and copy old onto the new.

Comment: Thank you hpaulj -- I need to create habit of looking into python/lib implementations.. :)

Comment: @Sendi_t I'm not quite sure what you mean. You can zero-out an array with `x1.fill(0)` if you want to "re-use" it. I don't know if that answers your question at all.